# PyOpenGL windows OS problem

Tags: opengl, pyopengl

So I've developed an application on Mac OS and now I'm trying to test it on a machine having windows XP. Now this doesn't work here first issue being that glGenBuffer and glGenBuffer are giving a NullFunctionException. So I tried to check the OpenGL version on that machine but glGetString(GL_VERSION) returns None. Problem is I don't know much about the machine I'm testing on. If I run a dxdiag direct X returns only n/a to all details about the video card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [gpu-caps](http://www.ozone3d.net/gpu_caps_viewer/?from-gpu-caps-viewer) to find out details, dxdiag can only be helpful in regards to directx. You might have to update graphic card drivers.